# Unable to test SOAP xml request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, soapui

I have trying to test a SOAP request in Jmeter tool. I have tested the same xml request in SOAPUI from the same machine and getting the correct response. But the  request is failing in Jmeter when I am using the SOAPXML/RPC Request Sampler. I have also tried using the HTTP request sampler and getting same response.

Response message which I received:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:157) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.SoapSampler.sample(SoapSampler.java:272) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am new to jmeter and this issue might be a common one to many of you. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Please share the SoapUI snapshot. I'll give you the jmeter equivalent.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam I am unable to send you the request or a snapshot. Can we connect through email ?

Comment: Yes. Sure. In my profile, you can check contact details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to run your request in SoapUI I would recommend recording it with JMeter.

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way would be using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) Feature.

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create`
   - Expand Workbench -> [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start" button

     [image: JMeter Recording from Template]
2. Configure SoapUI for running the request through JMeter proxy. From the main menu choose `File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings`, set Proxy Setting to `Manual` and populate Host and Port. If you are running SoapUI and JMeter on the same machine and using default JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder settings - go for `localhost` as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port

   [image: SoapUI Proxy Settings]
3. Run your request in SoapUI - JMeter will record it.

Going forward I would recommend using "normal" [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for web services load testing, check out [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual chapter for more details.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and trying to do the same but when i cahnge the proxy settings it does not run the request in soapui